# How can I add the extracted text from the webpage html into a text file on my computer?

Tags: python-3.x

I put together this code to grab text from a webpage and translate it into English. Rather than read the retrieved text in the PyCharm console, I want to export it into a text file to read later. How can I do this?

Also, do I need to add code to close the connection?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from googletrans import Translator

# Create object of Translator
translator = Translator()

url = "https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/warum-brennt-der-amazonas"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  
"))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

translated = translator.translate(text, dest='en')

print(translated)
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you're just taking the translated text and streaming it to the standard output (STDOUT) using `print`: you see this as the PyCharm console.

Instead, you want to stream it to a file. The typical syntax to do this in Python is:

```py
with open("your_file_name.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(translated.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

`translated` has type `Translated` which has an attribute `text`: this is what you want.

---

> Also, do I need to add code to close the connection?

No, when you make a HTTP request you can think of it basically as a "one-off thing" rather than a persistent connection. There's no need to close it as it isn't a persistent connection.

Note there are intricacies about TCP that might make this answer incomplete, but basically *no*, you don't need to close that connection.

Comment: Here's the error I get with this code. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AJ\Desktop\htmlscript\TranslationScript.py", line 31, in <module>
    f.write(translated.text)
  File "C:\Users\AJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 4842-4848: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: This is an encoding problem. I'm guessing you can solve this using `.encode("utf-8")` on `text`. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: Alright, so that code throws me a TypeError of write() argument must be str, not bytes.

Comment: Change the "w" (writing a text file) to a "wb". Sorry, encoding errors are a pain.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. The code finishes with an exit code 0 but when I open the .txt file on my desktop, it's blank?

Comment: I can't quite reproduce, unfortunately (macOS). The file looks a bit weird but it successfully is created. Are repeated attempts working? If not, does printing `translated.text.encode("utf-8")` work right before writing to file?

Comment: Adding that code prints the url basically but not the whole page and still doesn't export to a .txt file. This seems hopeless lol, thank you for all your help!

Comment: No worries. Again, this seems now to be a different issue: encoding. And it works on macOS and Linux, just not Windows.